# Cannot use '==' operator to compare two vectors

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a program for my Arduino Uno, but for some reason, I get the error

> no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Vector' and 'Vector')

on my second vector comparison, not the first.

Here is code that represents my problem.

```
#include <Vector.h>
void setup() {

}

void loop() {
  Vector<char> tACode; 
  Vector<char> aCode;
  aCode.push_back('0');
  aCode.push_back('0');
  aCode.push_back('0');
  Vector<char> nCode;
  nCode.push_back('0');
  nCode.push_back('0');
  if (tACode == aCode){
  }
  if (tACode == nCode){ 
  }
}
```

I have spent hours trying to figure out why this is happening, with no luck.
I would greatly appreciate a second pair of eyes.

Comment: The arduino Vector class does indeed not have a comparison operator. But this should throw an error for both comparisons, not only one of them.

Comment: @dave Okay, I see.  It was confusing me on why I only got the error message for one comparison.  
Thank you

Comment: @KileMaze Is it possible that it only give you one error because the compiler simply stopped after seeing one of the error, so it reported one error? Have you tried compiling each statement separately?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I did not try to compile each statement separately. I am sure that if I had, it would have given me an error for both, based on everyone's answers.  I guess I just thought that if the compiler had a direct issue with the '==' operator, then it would have given me an error for the first comparison and then stopped there.  I didn't see why it was only showing me an error for my second comparison.

Comment: @KileMaze It's possible that your compiler attempts to scan your code first and see if there's any error before actually compile them, and it happens to scan the second error first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at the definition of `Vector` it does not provide a `operator==`:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector();
    template <size_t MAX_SIZE>
    Vector(T(&values)[MAX_SIZE],
        size_t size = 0);
    template <size_t MAX_SIZE>
    void setStorage(T(&values)[MAX_SIZE],
        size_t size = 0);
    void setStorage(T* values,
        size_t max_size,
        size_t size);
    const T& operator[](size_t index) const;
    T& operator[](size_t index);
    const T& at(size_t index) const;
    T& at(size_t index);
    T& front();
    T& back();
    void clear();
    template <typename U>
    void fill(const U& value);
    template <typename U,
        size_t N>
        void fill(const U(&values)[N]);
    template <typename U>
    void fill(const Vector<U>& values);
    template <typename U>
    void assign(size_t n,
        const U& value);
    template <typename U,
        size_t N>
        void assign(size_t n,
            const U(&values)[N]);
    template <typename U>
    void assign(size_t n,
        const Vector<U>& values);
    void push_back(const T& value);
    void pop_back();
    void remove(size_t index);
    size_t size() const;
    size_t max_size() const;
    bool empty() const;
    bool full() const;
    const T* data() const;
    T* data();
    typedef VectorIterator<T> iterator;
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
    typedef VectorIterator<const T> const_iterator;
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;

private:
    T* values_;
    size_t max_size_;
    size_t size_;
};
```

but using these methods, you can define your own `operator==` at the start of the file (or put into your own file):

```
#include <Vector.h>

template <typename T>
inline bool operator==(const Vector<T>& vector1, const Vector<T>& vector2) {
    if (vector1.size() != vector2.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0u; i < vector1.size(); ++i) {
        if (vector1[i] != vector2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

now your == comparisons will work.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the definition of your `Vector` class, it might not have defined `operator==` for it.

Instead, you could first compare the size of them, if it has a way to access it, then compare each items in them.